# Conversion of Ruby Hashes to Sort array of Hash

Tags: ruby

I have following input:

```
array = [{:year=>2015, :platform_id=>2},
        {:year=>nil,  :platform_id=>2},
        {:year=>nil,  :platform_id=>4},
        {:year=>2015, :platform_id=>4}]
```

I need expected result to be:

```
[{platform_id=>2, year=>[2015, nil]},
 {platform_id=>4, year=>[nil, 2015]}]
```

What I code is:

```
array.inject(:merge)
```

But that gets me this result, which is not what I want:

```
{:year=>2015, :platform_id=>4}
```

Updated below after answer received:

**I do performance test after see the answers and here is the result:**

```
arr = [
  {:year => 2015, :platform_id => 2},
  {:year => nil, :platform_id => 2},
  {:year => nil, :platform_id => 4},
  {:year => 2015, :platform_id => 4}
]

#approach 1
x1 = Time.now.to_f
exp = arr.each_with_object({}) do |h, exp|
  exp[h[:platform_id]] ||= {:platform_id => h[:platform_id], :year => []}
  exp[h[:platform_id]][:year] << h[:year]
end.values
x2 = Time.now.to_f
p x2-x1

#approach 2
x3 = Time.now.to_f
new_data = arr.group_by { |d| d[:platform_id] }
new_arr = []
new_data.each do |k,v|
 t2 = v.map{|x| x[:year]}
 temp = {"platform_id": k, "years": t2}
 new_arr.push(temp)
end
x4 = Time.now.to_f
p x4-x3 

#approach 3
x5 = Time.now.to_f
f = arr.each_with_object({}) { |g,h|
  h.update(g[:platform_id]=>[g[:year]]) { |_,o,n| o+n } }
  #=> {2=>[2015, nil], 4=>[nil, 2015]} 

f.map { |k,v| { :platform_id=>k, :year=>v } }
x6 = Time.now.to_f
p x6-x5 

#output is:
9.059906005859375e-06
6.4373016357421875e-06
9.775161743164062e-06
```

Comment: If you just want the code done, you should hire a programmer to do it for you. But if you want to learn how to resolve this task yourself, you should try as much as you can and show us your progress and your exactly problem.

Comment: I have tried the inject, reduce but both give only first value. I am not sure whats wrong with these function.

Comment: could you please update your question with your actual requirement? What is your requirement to change 'year' element? 

If you just want to order your array of hash you can use `sort_by` with key.

Comment: sort_by is not working

Comment: just to sort your array based on `:platform_id`?

Comment: Don't knwo who give negative marks, even try to see problem. Please see answer

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and then modify your question with code showing your attempt to solve the problem. `array.inject(:merge)` isn't nearly enough to show effort so it looks like you want us to write the code for you. While you supply an answer it's not well related to the question because the problem is not well defined.

Comment: When you give an example, it's helpful to assign a variable to each input object (e.g., `arr = [{:year=>2015, :platform_id=>2},...]`). That way, readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having define them. Also, try to format your text so that horizontal scrolling is not needed to read your question. I'll edit your question to show you what I mean. (I trust you don't mind.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland You said: "if the asker had higher rep, you wouldn't be asking that". Do you really think this way?

Comment: @Garbriel, my answer would be based on my observations. Let me turn it around: can you find a *single question* authored by a member with rep > 20k in which the asker has been asked to explain what efforts he or she has made to solve the problem?

Comment: @CarySwoveland, Well, I can only say about myself. I would ask the very same thing even if the OP was Jon Skeet. But let's go deeper: A user with rep>20k probably wouldn't make a question that needs such a explanation, right? Anyway, I was a bit rude in my first comment, and this was my mistake. Also, it's a bit funny to see you trying to imply that I would have "more respect" for a user with high rep...

Comment: @Gabriel, I wasn't really thinking of your actions specifically. In fact, I would commend you if you asked the same of Mr. Skeet (or here, of, say, @JörgWMittag), but, statistically, I think you'd be as much of an outlier among SO members as Neptune is among the planets. (Such a comment would also bring knowing smiles to many faces.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland, "Such a comment would also bring knowing smiles to many faces". Why?

Comment: @Gabriel, it's a little like a famous mathematician asking his audience for suggested lines of attack to prove a conjecture and a student rising to assert that the audience was not prepared to help until the speaker demonstrated that he/she had made an effort to answer the question themself. Granted, in that case it would not be smiles, but horror-stricken faces.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I understand your point. Jon Skeet has proven he is a really smart guy and, being so smart, he presumably doesn't need an assert as in your example; but in an hypothetical scenario where Jon Skeet makes a bad question, I would be there to say "hey, your question isn't good because [...]". Having a high rep doesn't make him above any criticism (although, of course, the high rep is an indicative that he knows how to do the right thing).

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks, I am sure it is the best answer to most relative question, In fact such scenario required more in API.

Also, Gabriel stackoveflow is not to find and resolve bug but a platform to share scenario as well and know the approach.

Do you a question like "How to print in javascript" exists with 1000+ like in stackoveflow too.

Comment: @DineshSaini, when I read your question, I realized the lack of an explanation about what you have done. Anyway, I was too rude in my first comment to you and I'm sorry for this.

Comment: @Gabriel Its completely fine, when you give some time to stackoverflow, you will learn more. When you feel any lack of information just try to edit instead of a negative vote or close request :)  Don't worry it happens and no need to say sorry.

Comment: Oh! Just a side note: I didn't send a negative vote, nor a close request. I just commented, heh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr = [
  { :year=>2015, :platform_id=>2 }, 
  { :year=>nil,  :platform_id=>2 },
  { :year=>nil,  :platform_id=>4 },
  { :year=>2015, :platform_id=>4 }
]

arr.each_with_object({}) { |g,h|
  h.update(g[:platform_id]=>[g[:year]]) { |_,o,n| o+n } }.
    map { |k,v| { :platform_id=>k, :year=>v } }
    #=> [{:platform_id=>2, :year=>[2015, nil]},
    #    {:platform_id=>4, :year=>[nil, 2015]}]
```

The two steps are as follows.

```
f = arr.each_with_object({}) { |g,h|
  h.update(g[:platform_id]=>[g[:year]]) { |_,o,n| o+n } }
  #=> {2=>[2015, nil], 4=>[nil, 2015]} 

f.map { |k,v| { :platform_id=>k, :year=>v } }
  #=> [{:platform_id=>2, :year=>[2015, nil]},
  #    {:platform_id=>4, :year=>[nil, 2015]}]
```

The first step uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block (here `{ |_,o,n| o+n }`) that computes the value of keys that are present in both hashes being merged.

Comment: Thanks Cary for a detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `each_with_object` with hash and print values like this

```
arr = [
  {:year => 2015, :platform_id => 2},
  {:year => nil, :platform_id => 2},
  {:year => nil, :platform_id => 4},
  {:year => 2015, :platform_id => 4}
]

exp = arr.each_with_object({}) do |h, exp|
  exp[h[:platform_id]] ||= {:platform_id => h[:platform_id], :year => []}
  exp[h[:platform_id]][:year] << h[:year]
end.values

p exp
# => [{:platform_id=>2, :year=>[2015, nil]}, {:platform_id=>4, :year=>[nil, 2015]}]
```

Comment: Thanks, analyzing more optimized code Lukas and Carry

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
 data = [
 {:year=>2015, :platform_id=>2}, 
 {:year=>nil, :platform_id=>2},
 {:year=>nil, :platform_id=>4},
 {:year=>2015, :platform_id=>4}
]

new_data = data.group_by { |d| d[:platform_id] }


#p new_data

new_arr = []

new_data.each do |k,v|
 t2 = v.map{|x| x[:year]}
 temp = {"pf_id": k, "years": t2}
 new_arr.push(temp)
end

p new_arr
```

Comment: You're on the right track here with `group_by`, but remember that `map` is great for converting one array into another, saving the `x = []; y.each ... x.push(...)` part.